# How to populate a selection element with list of values NOT present in query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I have a date picker and selection element with a list of 5 possible time slots. The user can submit the date and time to a MySQL database. What I need is to query the date, get a list of the times that are already taken and populate the selection with only those times that HAVEN'T been taken. I feel like this should be easy but every time I get an idea I think of 4 reasons it won't work.

I'm using PHP and Javascript.

Comment: Make a call to your database which gets the Dates that are free and append them in your Select-Field.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a column to the table of interest such as "selected(bool)". When the date is selected set this field to true and update your query to search where selected = false.